Internal links in Nuget-flavoured markdown
I have a package with numerous small utility functions. Hence the readme needs a TOC/Index at a couple of levels for sensible navigation. I have saved the package to a Github repository, together with its readme.md file and have found that I can create the ToC/Index by eg
- [Topic Heading](#Topic1)
....
<a id="Topic1"></a>
### My Topic 1 Heading

However, I would then like to save the readme.md to NuGet when I publish the package. I find that the Github markdown format does not work within Nuget. The references are highlighted OK but the links do not connect.
I have tried
### My Topic 1(#Topic1)

with and without whitespace - no luck.
Can anyone help me with how to achieve an internal link in the Nuget markdown flavour, please?
So far as I can see, I have to create a new version of my package in Nuget in order to try something out. The 'CommonMark' spec seems only to cover the very basics and seems silent on this issue. Every markdown implementation appears to be a 'superset' of the standard, in which case what is the value of a standard? I can't find a comprehensive description of the Nuget flavour. Maintaining different versions of a readme file also seems unnecessarily wasteful. Markdown is driving me nuts!
